# MongoDB PHP - Group query

Tags: php, mongodb

Im trying to group count by the field publish_target

Using MYSQL I just did:

```
$postsByPlatform = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as `value`, `publish_target` as `key` FROM `Post` GROUP BY `publish_target` ");
$postsByPlatform = $postsByPlatform->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$return['Post']['publish_target'] = $postsByPlatform;
```

and got a result like this:

```
publish_target: [
{
value: "22",
key: "facebook"
},
{
value: "33",
key: "googleplus"
},
{
value: "44",
key: "instagram"
},
{
value: "55",
key: "other"
},
{
value: "66",
key: "twitter"
}
],
```

We are now converting to Mongo.

I have tried the example on PHP.net, adapted to this:

```
        // use all fields
        $keys = array('publish_target');

// set intial values
        $initial = array("count" => 0);

// JavaScript function to perform
        $reduce = "function (obj, prev) { prev.count++; }";

// only use documents where the "a" field is greater than 1

        $g = $collection->group($keys, $initial, $reduce);

        var_dump($g);
```

But this just returns

```
array(4) {
  'retval' =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    array(1) {
      'count' =>
      double(100)
    }
  }
  'count' =>
  double(100)
  'keys' =>
  int(1)
  'ok' =>
  double(1)
}
```

Which means nothing to me.

How do I do this correctly?

Comment: You can use the aggregation framework: `db.col.aggregate([{$group: {_id: '$publish_target', value: {$sum: 1} }}])` Easy enough to translate to PHP that one is

Comment: Tried:

        $collection = $this->mongoDB->Post;
       $out = $collection->aggregate(array('$group' => array('_id' => '$publish_target', 'value' => array('$sum' => 1))));

The output wasnt great. array(3) {
  'errmsg' =>
  string(11) "no such cmd"
  'bad cmd' =>
  array(2) {
    'aggregate' =>
    string(4) "Post"
    'pipeline' =>
    array(1) {
      '$group' =>
      array(2) {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
  'ok' =>
  double(0)
}

Comment: Hmm you might running an old mongodb version if it says there is not aggregate command, in which as anh said it is because you didn't put true there

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the issue, but comparing with my own code this line

```
$keys = array('publish_target');
```

should look like this

```
$keys = array('publish_target' => true);
```